# Вернуть True, если запись отсутствует, или присутствует, но добавлена более 10 минут назад

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно вернуть True в любом из двух случаев - если запись существует, но при этом добавлена более 10 минут назад, или вернуть True, если запись отсутствует. Смотрел в сторону этого:

```
SELECT EXISTS( SELECT id 
               FROM table 
               WHERE use_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE 
                 AND что тут нужно добавить )
```

Но что тут нужно добавить, в голову не приходит

Comment: а если с другой стороны посмотреть, то это надо проверить наличие записи меньшей чем 10 минут.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id 
                    FROM table 
                    WHERE use_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )
```

Answer (score 0):

То что вы написали будет эквивалентно отсутствуют записи меньшей чем 10 минут.

Вы описали логическое выражение

```
exists && t>10 || !exists
```

Попробуйте его переформулировать с отрицанием

```
!( (!exists || t < 10 ) && exists )
```

раскройте скобки в &&

```
!( !exists && exists || (t< 10 && exists))
```

очевидно, первая часть всегда false и из OR это можно выкинуть, останется

```
!(exists && t < 10)
```